# I'm trying to make a programme which flashes an image when the "a" key is pressed

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyup

```html
<div class="planeta" id="planeta">
  <img src="planeta.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
  <div class="text-blocka">
    <h4>Kepler-186f</h4>
    <p>550 light years away</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first part of the code works and the image begins to flash, but i want it to cancel the flash when the key is released and this part is not working for me. Below is the javascript i have written so far. Thanks in advance!

```
function checkKeydowna(akey) {
    if (akey.keyCode == "65") {
      var img = document.getElementById('planeta');

var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(img.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
      img.style.visibility == 'hidden'
      }
}, 50);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyupa, false);

function checkKeyupa(abkey) {
    if (abkey.keyCode == "65") {
    delete window.setInterval();
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can show you HTML , please ?

Comment: One quick note, in javascript it's best practice to use triple equals for equality (e.g. akey.keyCode === "65"). In this case it doesn't matter, but it prevents unexpected outcomes that might come from type conversion wonkiness in javascript. Mozilla has some helpful docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You forgot `addEventListener` for `checkKeydowna`.
- `delete window.setInterval();` is meaningless. that doesn't clear interval. you should clear interval with `window.clearInterval(intervalInstance)`. So if you want to clear an interval you should store that in a global varible when you set it. That is why I declare `var interval = false;` which also means interval didn't set.
- Keydown event will be triggered multiple times, so you should check if interval is set or not to avoid reinitialize it.

```js
var interval = false;
function checkKeydowna(akey) {
  if (akey.keyCode == "65") {
    var img = document.getElementById('planeta');

    if (!interval) {
      interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (img.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
          img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
          img.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        }
      }, 50);
    }
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyupa, false);
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeydowna, false);

function checkKeyupa(abkey) {
  if (abkey.keyCode == "65") {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    interval = false;
    var img = document.getElementById('planeta');
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

```html
<img style='visibility:visible' src="https://www.google.com.tr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" id="planeta" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put checkKeyupa in SetTimeout or setInterval.

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>setTimeout(checkKeyupa, 50), false);
```

Since you need to make sure checkKeyupa goes in event queue behind interval and executes after interval get's executed.